# Python2.7 ImportError: cannot import name sigtools

Tags: python, scipy

I'm running python 2.7.10 on Windows 7 and 8 and receive this message on both machines

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    import prefilt
  File "prefilt.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scipy.signal import butter,lfilter
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\__init__.py", line 256, in <module>
    from . import sigtools
ImportError: cannot import name sigtools
```

every time, when i try to import the script, with its first line being

```
from scipy.signal import lfilter,butter
```

What can it be connected with?

Comment: sigtools is an extension module, it needs to be compiled. How did you install scipy?

Comment: Most likely a build error: to confirm, please go into the directory
where sigtools.so is located and do a direct import:

python -c "import sigtools"

Comment: It was installed via Python(x,y) from their official site

Comment: Windows doesn't find sigtools.so on any of the two machines.

Comment: In the directory ../scipy/signal there is a file sigtools.pyd

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on a Gentoo Linux machine, and gmuraleekrishna's suggestions worked perfectly. So let's call it an answer:

Step 1: Find the directory where sigtools.so is located. I used a particularly stupid brute force approach, and run  "find / -name sigtools.*" in a shell.

Step 2: Go into the directory where sigtools.so is located and do a direct import. E.g. run

python -c "import sigtools"

Step 3: go back to your project and "import scipy.signal" normally in your program / prompt.